# How to remove special characters at the Beginning and End of the string and not for numeric?

Tags: c#

In string array, I have list of strings and I want to remove special characters from them only if it appears at the beginning or end of the string. And also if a special character appears before or after any numeric value then I do not want to remove that character.

- If a word starts or ends with any special character then that special character should be removed.
- If a word contains any special character in between a word
  then that should be ignored. (i.e., Top-Up should remain as
  Top-Up)
- If a numeric value has any special character then that should be
  ignored. (i.e., #55 & $55.00 should remain as it is.)

For example :

```
string[] words = { "#(Super-Good)", "22\"", "#50", "2.20GHz," , "[Personal})]" , "$44.00", "55\"" };


string[] splChars = new string[] { "#", "$", ",", "/", "!", "@", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "'", "\"", ";", "_", ":", "|", "[", "]" };
List<string> wrdLst = new List<string>();
string[] tmpWrd;
foreach (string wrd in words)
{
    tmpWrd = wrd.Split(chars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tmpWrd.FirstOrDefault()))
    wrdLst.Add(string.Join(wrd, tmpWrd));
}

Expected O/P:
Super-Good
22"
#50
2.20GHz
Personal
$44.00
55"
```

Comment: Define "special". The results don't match the description, eg `Super-Good` doesn't contain any numbers, so why were the parentheses stripped?

Comment: What *is* a "special" character in this case? `-`, #1, `$` aren't treated as special. Parentheses, square and angle brackets seem to be "special" and *always* removed. Are you sure you don't just want to remove parentheses and brackets?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I have updated my question. Special characters should be ignored if a word is numeric value.

Comment: So would `#abc` result in `abc`?

Comment: @Llama - Yes, you're right. #abc should be abc and #55 should be #55.

Comment: @Ask_SO not according to the expected results. Post results that actually match what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to reproduce your issue, I created this class containing your initial attempt to solve the problem - I've refactored it a bit and renamed some of the variables, but I believe this is functionally identical to the code in your question.

```
namespace StackOverflow69116104SpecialChars
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    public class Cleaner
    {
        private readonly string[] specialCharacters = { "#", "$", ",", "/", "!", "@", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "'", "\"", ";", "_", ":", "|", "[", "]" };

        public string[] Original(string[] words)
        {
            var cleaned = new List<string>();
            foreach (string word in words)
            {
                var split = word.Split(specialCharacters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(split.FirstOrDefault()))
                {
                    cleaned.Add(string.Join(word, split));
                }
            }

            return cleaned.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Next step, I created a unit test using your inputs and expected outputs. I've used the Xunit testing framework, but you could do the same using any unit testing framework for .net.

```
namespace StackOverflow69116104SpecialChars
{
    using System.Text;
    using Xunit;

    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            // Arrange
            var uncleanWords = new string[]
            {
                "#(Super-Good)",
                "22\"",
                "#50",
                "2.20GHz,",
                "[Personal})]",
                "$44.00",
                "55\"",
            };

            var expectedCleanedWords = new string[]
            {
                "Super-Good",
                "22\"",
                "#50",
                "2.20GHz",
                "Personal",
                "$44.00",
                "55\"",
            };

            // Act
            var cleaner = new Cleaner();
            var actualCleanedWords = cleaner.Original(uncleanWords);

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal(expectedCleanedWords.Length, actualCleanedWords.Length);
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (var i = 0; i < expectedCleanedWords.Length; i++)
            {
                if (expectedCleanedWords[i] != actualCleanedWords[i])
                {
                    sb.AppendLine($"At index {i} expected '{expectedCleanedWords[i]}' but was '{actualCleanedWords[i]}'.");
                }
            }

            if (sb.Length > 0)
            {
                throw new Xunit.Sdk.XunitException(sb.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This fails with the message

```
At index 1 expected '22"' but was '22'.
At index 2 expected '#50' but was '50'.
At index 4 expected 'Personal' but was 'Personal}'.
At index 5 expected '$44.00' but was '44.00'.
At index 6 expected '55"' but was '55'.
```

The first failure, `expected '22"' but was '22'` is happening because there's no code to meet this requirement:

> If a numeric value has any special character then that should be ignored. (i.e., #55 & $55.00 should remain as it is.)

There's no test for whether the string, minus the special characters, is a numeric value (which I'm going to interpret as consisting of the characters `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `0` or `.`), so let's try implementing that in a new method called `Revision1`, with the help of a new private method called `IsNumeric`.

```
public string[] Revision1(string[] words)
{
    var cleaned = new List<string>();
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        var split = word.Split(specialCharacters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var rejoined = string.Join(word, split);
        if (IsNumeric(rejoined))
        {
            // It's a numeric, so return it with its special characters
            cleaned.Add(word);
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(split.FirstOrDefault()))
        {
            cleaned.Add(rejoined);
        }
    }

    return cleaned.ToArray();
}

private static bool IsNumeric(string mightBeNumeric)
{
    var r = new Regex(@"^[0-9\.]+$");
    var match = r.Match(mightBeNumeric);
    return match.Success;
}
```

And update the unit test to call this method instead of the original method:

```
// Act
var cleaner = new Cleaner();
var actualCleanedWords = cleaner.Revision1(uncleanWords);
```

The unit test still fails, but in a better way - only one failure now:

```
At index 4 expected 'Personal' but was 'Personal}'.
```

The failure at index 4 is pretty easy to fix - you've omitted `}` (and probably `{`) from your definition of special characters. Just change `specialCharacters` to

```
private readonly string[] specialCharacters = { "#", "$", ",", "/", "!", "@", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "'", "\"", ";", "_", ":", "|", "[", "]", "{", "}" };
```

Now the unit test passes.

#### Update 18th Sep

After I posted the original answer, @Ask_SO commented

> In your code, I do not see logic to remove at the Beginning and End of the string. With this code, it removes special characters from entire string.

So I added another test case - `abc#def`, which should stay unchanged. Rather surprisingly, it came out as `abcabc#defdef`.

Looking more closely at the test cases, I noticed that there weren't any to cover a string with special characters at the start and end (which should be removed) and also in the middle (which shouldn't be removed). So I added these to the unit test, along with an empty string (just because that might prove to be problematic).

```
var uncleanWords = new string[]
{
    "abc#def",
    "$,abc#@def{}",
    "_^abc#def@ghi,,",
    "",
    "#(Super-Good)",
    "22\"",
    "#50",
    "2.20GHz,",
    "[Personal})]",
    "$44.00",
    "55\"",
};

var expectedCleanedWords = new string[]
{
    "abc#def",
    "abc#@def",
    "abc#def@ghi",
    "",
    "Super-Good",
    "22\"",
    "#50",
    "2.20GHz",
    "Personal",
    "$44.00",
    "55\"",
};
```

The unit test now fails on the new test cases, so I came up with a new implementation in a method called `Revision2`.

```
public string[] Revision2(string[] words)
{
    var cleaned = new List<string>();
    foreach (var word in words)
    {
        var split = word.Split(specialCharacters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var isNumeric = true;
        foreach (var bit in split)
        {
            if (!IsNumeric(bit))
            {
                // Part of the string is neither numeric nor a special character
                // so we will need to remove special characters from the start
                // and end.
                isNumeric = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isNumeric)
        {
            // return the whole string unchanged
            cleaned.Add(word);
        }
        else
        {
            // we need to remove special characters from the start and end
            int firstNonSpecialCharacterPosition = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!this.specialCharacters.Contains(word[i]))
                {
                    firstNonSpecialCharacterPosition = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            int lastNonSpecialCharacterPosition = word.Length;
            for (var i = word.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                if (!this.specialCharacters.Contains(word[i]))
                {
                    lastNonSpecialCharacterPosition = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
                    
            var lengthToKeep = (lastNonSpecialCharacterPosition - firstNonSpecialCharacterPosition) + 1;
            var newWord = word.Substring(firstNonSpecialCharacterPosition, lengthToKeep);
            cleaned.Add(newWord);
        }
    }

    return cleaned.ToArray();
}
```

This implementation passes the updated unit test. This is one of the reasons unit tests are important - when following a test-driven development approach, they provide an unambiguous definition of the expected behaviour of the code.

Comment: In your code, I do not see logic to remove at the Beginning and End of the string. With this code, it removes special characters from entire string.

Comment: Ah, I've just noticed that your description says "If a word contains any special character in between a word then that should be ignored. (i.e., Top-Up should remain as Top-Up)" but your code doesn't treat `-` as a special character. Should `-` be a special character? Should `abc#def` stay as `abc#def`? If so then we need to include that as a test case. (Having tried it, `abc#def` actually comes out as `abcabc#defdef`, which would have raised a flag that something was wrong if it was in the unit test).

Comment: It is working fine. Thanks much for your effort!